# node.js: create a connected writable and readable stream pair

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to create a function that returns a connected writable and readable stream pair. eg:

```
const { writable, readable } = createStreamPair();
```

where each end has the right interface (`writable instanceof stream.Readable === false` and `readable instanceof stream.Writable === false`) unlike the PassThrough stream.

use case:

```
createWriteStream(filePath) {

    const { writable, readable } = createStreamPair();
    writeFile(filePath, readable);
    return writable;
}
```

How to create my `createStreamPair()` function ?

**Edit1**

A naive approach that obviously does not work ...

```
function createStreamPair() {

    var readable = new stream.Readable();
    var writable = new stream.Writable();
    readable.pipe(writable);
    return { writable, readable }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Node.js tests uses a function that creates two Duplex streams, writes to one can be read from the other, and vice-versa: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/test/common/duplexpair.js

It isn't part of the Node.js standard library, but you can write your own.

I'll present a slightly modified, annotated version here:

```
const Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;
const assert = require('assert');

// Define some unique property names.
// The actual value doesn't matter,
// so long as they're not used by Node.js for anything else.
const kCallback = Symbol('Callback');
const kOtherSide = Symbol('Other');

// Define a function `DuplexSocket` whose prototype inherits from `Duplex`
class DuplexSocket extends Duplex {
    constructor() {
        // Let Node.js initialize everything it needs to
        super();
        // Define two values we will be using
        // kCallback saves a temporary reference to a function while
        this[kCallback] = null;
        // kOtherSide will be the reference to the other side of the stream
        this[kOtherSide] = null;
    }

    _read() {
        // This is called when this side receives a push() call
        // If the other side set a callback for us to call,
        // then first clear that reference
        // (it might be immediately set to a new value again),
        // then call the function.
        const callback = this[kCallback];
        if (callback) {
            this[kCallback] = null;
            callback();
        }
    }

    _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        // This is called when someone writes to the stream
        // Ensure there's a reference to the other side before trying to call it
        assert.notStrictEqual(this[kOtherSide], null);
        // Ensure that the other-side callback is empty before setting it
        // If push immediately calls _read, this should never be a problem
        assert.strictEqual(this[kOtherSide][kCallback], null);
        if (chunk.length === 0) {
            // callback is not called for zero-length chunks
            process.nextTick(callback);
        } else {
            // Let Node.js know when _read has been called
            this[kOtherSide][kCallback] = callback;
            // And finally, send the other side the data to be read
            this[kOtherSide].push(chunk);
        }
    }

    _final(callback) {
        // Ask the other side to let us know it received our EOF request
        this[kOtherSide].on('end', callback);
        // And finally, pushing null signals the end of the stream
        this[kOtherSide].push(null);
    }
}

function makeDuplexPair() {
    // Create two pairs of 
    const clientSide = new DuplexSocket();
    const serverSide = new DuplexSocket();
    // Set the other-side reference
    clientSide[kOtherSide] = serverSide;
    serverSide[kOtherSide] = clientSide;
    // Both instances behave the same, so choice of name doesn't matter,
    // So long as they're distinguishable.
    return { clientSide, serverSide };
}

module.exports = makeDuplexPair;
```

Here's another way of creating two streams, one Readable and one Writable in this case:

```
function makeAsymmetricalStreamPair() {
    var readableCallback;
    const readableSide = new ReadableStream;
    readableSide._read = function _read(){
        if(!readableCallback) return;
        var callback = readableCallback;
        readableCallback = null;
        callback();
    }
    const writableSide = new WritableStream;
    writableSide._write = function _write(chunk, enc, callback){
        if (readableCallback) throw new Error;
        if (chunk.length === 0) {
            process.nextTick(callback);
        } else {
            readableCallback = callback;
            readableSide.push(chunk);
        }
    }
    writableSide._final = function _final(callback){
        readableSide.on('end', callback);
        readableSide.push(null);
    }
    return { readableSide, writableSide };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of today you can use stream.PassTrough